# Jquery's callback execution order with success and when

Tags: javascript, jquery

having the following code, whats the order of execution of the callback functions?

According to my tests `showData()` is always executed last, but these are pretty light operations, if i had more complex operations, does the `$.when(...).then(callback)` always wait for the `success` callbacks to finish before executing? here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6v6gu6kc/1/) for easier testing.

```
function showData() {
      console.log("show data after when");
    //can i be sure that method1 success and method2 success have finished?
}

function method1() {
    return $.ajax('https://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/', {
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(){ console.log("method 1 success")}
    });
}

function method2() {
    return $.ajax('https://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/', {
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(){ console.log("method 2 success")}
    });
}

$.when(method1(), method2()).then(showData);
```

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point of `$.when()`.

Comment: Thanks, i just wanted to make sure because I couldn't find a similar test on the [official docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), as they always handle the data on the `.then`  `callback(data1, data2)`

Answer (score 0):

According to this information from [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

> Description: Provides a way to execute callback functions based on zero or more Thenable objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

`$.when()` provides a way to execute your callback function *in that case* `showData()` function.

Yep, that will work as you predicted.